# Problem with [man, floatsintext]{apa6} and tables

Tags: tables, floats, apa6

I am working recently with LaTeX and now I have a problem which I do not solve. I want to include every table and every figure in my document text, but it does not work and shows the floats at the end of the document.

My document is an Manual [man] of the apa6 package. After some research I found out that this problem is a common one and found the "`floatsintext`"-option in the apa6 manual as a solution which should include all floats into my document. After adding this into my code all figures were now in my document text as I want, but all tables are still at the end of the document.

I tried the `\resizebox` command but it does not help.
I also tried an shorter example of my code and it works, but in the larger document it doesn`t.

If it helps, here is the code of the shorter example which works.

```
\documentclass[man, floatsintext]{apa6}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{bla1}
bla bla bla.

\begin{table} [!htbp]
\caption{Comparison of dynamic changes}
\resizebox{10cm}{!}{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX|XX}
\hline
& Characteristics & Measurement point t0 & Measurement point t1 \\
\midrule
& Missings & 0 & 4 \\
& Density & 0.044 & 0.070 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{table}

\section{bla2}
bla bla bla.

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: To easiest way to prevent tables and figures from floating is to include them without the floating environment, i.e., remove `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` and `\caption`. If you still want captions you can look at the `capt-of` package that provides captions for non-floats.

Comment: only apply `\resizebox{10cm}{!}{` to tables as a last resort, and even then try to avoid it. It will make inconsistent font sizes and rule widths and can easily produce unreadably small text. Here tabularx makes a table the width of the text block, then you add a word space to either side and scale the resulting combination to 10cm wide?

Comment: The floats are not at the end, generally. Add text and you'll see.

Comment: @Marijn: Thanks for the idea. If I use the `\captionof` command instead of the table environment, the caption made by `\captionof` lays always  above the other text in the document. 
@David Carlisle: Thanks for your advice. `\resizebox` was just an option to see if the width of the table is the problem why it is not included in the document text. 
@egreg: In the Manual-class of the apa6 package the floats are normally at the end of the document. Sorry if I don`t get your point.

Comment: You wrote: "I also tried an shorter example of my code and it works, but in the larger document it doesn`t." Without seeing what you did differently in your large document, it is impossible to tell you why it does not work as expected. Therefore, please take a copy of your large document, comment out a part, recompile and see if the issue persists. If so, repeat until you get the smalles possible document that still produces the issue. This will then be a suitable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that others can use to work with.

Comment: Upon removing `\resizebox{...}`, the table float appears to respect the `[htbp]` options.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a couple of times and I would usually use `resizebox` to get rid off it. I believe this is totally fine to do because the manuscript is just that---a manuscript; it is not the final publication. The typesetter will have to deal with the table anyway and will likely rearrange it. Instead of 10cm you could use `\textwidth`.

I disagree with not using floats. It is not necessary and this is not how the apa6 package is supposed be used.

By the way, if your tables do not fit on the page, maybe you can change them. For instance, you seem to use quite verbose column names. They could be abbreviated. You can always check how a final paper might look like by using the `jou` option instead of `man` (consider changing the tables to two columns in this case). If your table looks fine there, I would not bother working on it and just resize it to the text width.

Another option is to check out the longtable section in the `apa6` manual. But this is only for cases where your table is longer than one page.

If resizing to text width does not work, provide a MWE, please.